# SpringFramework: Configuration issue: Id is required for element

Tags: spring

I am deploying applications to J2EE server with the following spring xml declaration.

```
<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="XMLToCSVConverter_prop" location="classpath://XMLToCSVConverter/resources/parameters.prop"/>
```

However I am getting a configuration problem because of the property-placeHolder,
Configuration problem: Id is required for element 'propertyPlaceholder' when used as a top-level tag.

I have no idea how to fix this. The property-placeHolder element does not have an Id attribute so I cannot set any values there. Please help some one.

Thanks